# How to Ensure local data has not been tampered with

Tags: security, server, theory

Let's say I have an application that pays users to process a certain amount of data, say 500 Mb. After the processing has completed, the application contacts an online server to notify it that the data has been processed and receive payment. Now let's say the application either loses connection to the server, or crashes in the middle of processing and we want to save how much data we've already processed. We can save this as a file on the computer, but we want to prevent the user from finding the file and modifying it, making it look like they've processed more data and in turn getting paid for work that wasn't done.

The data that is processed is not sent back to the server, so there is no way to directly verify the processing happened, the application just counts how much data was processed and notifies the server when enough has been completed to be paid.

How would you secure and verify that the local counter hasn't been modified?

Comment: You should also consider that data in memory can be tampered with (especially when that data is used to calculate $$$)

Comment: How does your application authenticate itself to the server doing payments? If you are doing this securely, one would think you could use that mechanism to secure data locally as well. You are securing the server, right?

Comment: Also - how do they get this data? Do you give it to them? Do you know what it is? You might be able to at least guarantee they have *read* all the data if they hope to claim the prize money.